# How to get html content using CyberNeko?

Tags: html, groovy, xmlslurper, cyberneko

```
def page = new XmlSlurper(new SAXParser()).parse(url)
println  page.body[0]
```

I want output

```
 <body>
   <h1>Header</h1>
 </body>
```

where my html is:

```
   <html>
       <head>
           <title>Title</title>
       </head>
       <body>
             <h1>Header</h1>
       </body>
   </html>
```

But my output is

```
Header
```

How to tell xmlSluper to take the code, not the content?

Comment: Not at a computer, so this is a guess `println XmlUtil.serialise( page.body[0])`

Comment: Correct `XmlUtil.serialize( page.body[0] )`. `.serialize()` with a `z`..... [*We all live in Americaaa*](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xFVdvXGIT34).... :P @tim_yates

Comment: Stupid phone autocorrect ;-)

Comment: OK. That works, but can we use some of XmlSluper methods, instead of this *util* method. Just ask. Yours answers are good for me.

Comment: @Xelian Unfortunatley not, `XmlSlurper` doesn't handle serialization, you need to use `XmlUtil` methods or something like `StreamingMarkupBuilder`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To serialize data, you need to use some sort of serializer such as `XmlUtil.serialize` or `StreamingMarkupBuilder`, ie:

```
println XmlUtil.serialize( page.body[0] )
```

or:

```
new groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind { mkp.yield page.body }.toString()
```